# How to completely delete and reinstall a printer driver?

Tags: drivers, printing

The printer has some issues and I believe that if I delete completely the printer driver and then I reinstall it, it will work.

How can I do this?

Removing the printer and then adding it again doesn't deletes the driver I guess.

Comment: Generally "System Settings" > "Printers" should list your printers There may be several for each printer - with differing settings (I have one for photos, another for text - output to same printer). Right click the one you wish to change/delete - find the "uri" field and COPY & KEEP the text in there - as a backup at least. Remove the printe: right click and select "Delete" in the menu. [This search](http://askubuntu.com/search?q=install+printer) should help you back. It **should** be as simple as clicking "Add +" and then enter the "Uri" from above.

Comment: @Hannu I already did that, but does it really deletes the driver?

Comment: "delete driver" - no not likely, for that you will need to find out which package that contains the driver and `apt-get purge driver` on that. But before doing so I'd google some on `+printer_name +ubuntu +driver` - you might find other having the same "issue".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few methods to find out which package got installed when trying to install the driver for the printer. Here are 3 that I know:

1. Seach for currently installed printer releated packages

   ```
   aptitude search printer | grep ^i
   i   epson-inkjet-printer-escpr      - Epson Inkjet Printer Driver (ESC/P-R) for 
   i   indicator-printers              - indicator showing active print jobs       
   i   printer-driver-c2esp            - printer driver for Kodak ESP AiO color ink
   i   printer-driver-foo2zjs          - printer driver for ZjStream-based printers
   i   printer-driver-foo2zjs-common   - printer driver for ZjStream-based printers
   i   printer-driver-gutenprint       - printer drivers for CUPS                  
   i   printer-driver-hpcups           - HP Linux Printing and Imaging - CUPS Raste
   i   printer-driver-min12xxw         - printer driver for KonicaMinolta PagePro 1
   i   printer-driver-pnm2ppa          - printer driver for HP-GDI printers        
   i   printer-driver-postscript-hp    - HP Printers PostScript Descriptions       
   i   printer-driver-ptouch           - printer driver Brother P-touch label print
   i   printer-driver-pxljr            - printer driver for HP Color LaserJet 35xx/
   i   printer-driver-sag-gdi          - printer driver for Ricoh Aficio SP 1000s/S
   i   printer-driver-splix            - Driver for Samsung and Xerox SPL2 and SPLc
   i   system-config-printer-common    - Printer configuration GUI                 
   i   system-config-printer-gnome     - Printer configuration GUI                 
   i   system-config-printer-udev      - Printer auto-configuration facility based
   ```
2. Search through your APT history for recently installed printer related packages

   ```
   cat /var/log/apt/history.log | grep -e ^Install | grep printer
   zcat /var/log/apt/history.log.*.gz | grep -e ^Install | grep printer
   ```
3. Use the [Ubuntu packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) site to search for packages that provide drivers for your printer by searching for package names *and* package descriptions. You should not only search for the exact model number but also try just searching for the maker. Most packages have a [uniform naming scheme](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=printer-driver&searchon=names).

By combining these methods you should be able to find the proper package and remove it with `apt-get purge $package-name`. In my case I found that I installed a package named `epson-inkjet-printer-escpr`.

You may want to also remove the packages from `/var/cache/apt/archives/` and `/var/cache/apt/archives/partial/` or purge the entire local package cache with `sudo apt-get clean`.

**Caution:** You should be careful when removing packages, removing all printer related packages with a wildcard may damage your installation. Usual indicators for removing the wrong packages is a very long list of packages that will be removed or the `ubuntu-desktop` package being among them.