# I have installed my printer but it prints symbols continuously

Tags: drivers, printing, epson

I have installed my printer Epson L120 Series. I have already set it up on CUPS, followed instructions to install its driver, but whenever I print something (even images) the result is continuous printing of symbols and the printer doesn't stop unless I stop it or until it runs out of paper.

[image: sample printed result]

- Driver: `epson-inkjet-printer-201310w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_i386.deb`
- OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
- Printer: Epson L120 Series

Comment: Please provide more details like which OS you're using, driver version, etc.

Comment: Details are already updated, ty

Comment: What is the exact model number of your printer? Is [this](https://www.epson.com.ph/Ink-Tank-Printers/L-Series/Epson-L120/s/SPT_C11CD76401?review-filter=Linux) your printer?

Comment: Yes that's the exact model of my printer

Comment: Did you install the LSB package?

Comment: yes, i have installed it when i downloaded the driver

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111744/discussion-between-technastic-tc-and-kenzerxii).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got it!

Before, I have installed **epson-inkjet-printer-201310w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_i386.deb** I didn't realize it was for 32bit PC but my machine was 64bit. So I downloaded **epson-inkjet-printer-201310w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb** 64bit driver.

1. I checked my recent printer driver using `aptitude search printer | grep ^i`
2. I removed my recent printer drivers using `sudo apt-get purge $package-name` in my case `sudo apt-get purge epson-inkjet-printer-201310w`. See [How to completely delete and reinstall printer driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/482375/how-to-completely-delete-and-reinstall-a-printer-driver)  And on my **Settings** I removed my printer.
3. I restarted my machine and reinstalled the driver which I downloaded from [here on the epson website](https://www.epson.com.ph/Ink-Tank-Printers/L-Series/Epson-L120/s/SPT_C11CD76401?review-filter=Linux) `epson-inkjet-printer-201310w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb`
4. I added my printer again from the **Settings**, went to **Additional Printer Settings** > double click my printer icon > from **Test and Maintenance** I clicked on **Print Test Page**, waited for my printer to configure itself and voila! it worked!

Comment: Please mention in the answer that you installed a different driver than compared to the driver mentioned in the question and also the reason why you had to install a different driver.

Comment: For me I had to do `sudo apt-get purge epson-inkjet-printer-escpr -y` then install the proper driver from http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule